# Calculating Phase difference

Tags: oscillators

Based on the image below, you can see two waves. The black wave is phase shifted towards the left.
If I know their starting positions 3$^{\circ}$ and 5$^{\circ}$ respectively for the black and blue waves, is it possible to calculate the phase difference between the two based on the equation and information listed below?

$$\theta(t) = \theta_{max}\:cos(\omega t + \varphi) $$

Known variables; $\omega$ , $t$ , $\theta_{max}$ and period

[image: Original wave and Phase shifted wave]

Comment: Do you know what phase difference is? Look it up and you’ll have your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, try to substitute $t=0$ in the equation for $\theta(t)$ for both the blue wave and the black wave, and use the information you can read from the graph:
$$\theta_\text{blue}(0)=5^\circ$$
$$\theta_\text{black}(0)=3^\circ$$
And the maximum amplitude, which is $5^\circ$ for both waves. Then you are left with the two phases $\varphi$ for which you only need to solve the equation.